# Want some text to erase its self in game

Tags: c++, 2d-games, allegro5

Ok so just kind of want to know a trick to get around this.

So i want the text "window will close in 10 seconds" to erase every time it goes through the loop and replace with the next number counting down. But all i get now is overlapping.

I just want it to count down and display as it goes.

```
//FILE: Main.cpp
//PROGR: Hank Bates
//PURPOSE: To display text on screen for 10 seconds. 
//EXTRA ADD ON FILES: Slendermanswriting.ttf
//                    PrometheusSiren.wav


#include <allegro5\allegro.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_font.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_ttf.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_native_dialog.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_audio.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_acodec.h>


int main(void)
{
    //summon the fonts and stuff
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_FONT *font50;
    ALLEGRO_FONT *font36;
    ALLEGRO_FONT *font18;
    ALLEGRO_SAMPLE *song;
    int a = 100;


    if (!al_init())
    {
        al_show_native_message_box(NULL, NULL, NULL,
            "failed to initialize allegro!", NULL, NULL);
        return -1;
    }

    //set up some of the display settings
    al_set_new_display_flags(ALLEGRO_WINDOWED | ALLEGRO_RESIZABLE);
    display = al_create_display(640, 480);
    al_set_window_title(display, "A bad horror game");

    if (!display)
    {
        al_show_native_message_box(NULL, NULL, NULL,
            "failed to initialize display!", NULL, NULL);
        return -1;
    }

    al_init_font_addon();
    al_init_ttf_addon();

    //Install Slender Man font here
    font50 = al_load_font("Slendermanswriting.ttf", 50, 0);
    font36 = al_load_font("Slendermanswriting.ttf", 36, 0);
    font18 = al_load_font("Slendermanswriting.ttf", 18, 0);

    //set up music here
    al_install_audio();
    al_init_acodec_addon();
    al_reserve_samples(1);

    song = al_load_sample("PrometheusSiren.wav");

    //play song this will loop around and around like a record man!
    al_play_sample(song, 1, 0, 1, ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE_LOOP, NULL);

    int screen_w = al_get_display_width(display);
    int screen_h = al_get_display_height(display);

    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0));

    al_draw_text(font50, al_map_rgb(255, 0, 0), 12, 50, 0, "SLENDER MAN IS COMING");
    al_draw_text(font36, al_map_rgb(255, 5, 10), 200, 100, 0,  "RUN AND HIDE");
    al_draw_text(font18, al_map_rgb(100, 15, 18), 150, 150, 0,  "ENJOY THE PROMETHEUS SIREN MUSIC");

    int timer = 10;
while (timer != 0)
    {


al_draw_textf(font18, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), screen_w / 3, 300, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTRE,
        "TURN UP YOUR VOLUME TO %i PRECENT!", a);

    al_draw_textf(font18, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), screen_w / 2, 400, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTRE,
        "WINDOW WILL CLOSE IN %i seconds!", timer);

    al_flip_display();


        al_rest(1.0);
        timer = timer - 1;
    }



    al_rest(10.0);

    //destroy stuff
    al_destroy_font(font18);
    al_destroy_font(font50);
    al_destroy_font(font36);
    al_destroy_display(display);
    al_destroy_sample(song); 
    //pew pew pew, bang.... all destoryed :)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Haven't used allegro in about 15 years myself. Though it seems that you'll need to make use of one of the bitmap functions. Depending on the background behind the text, you may need to redraw a bitmap, before drawing the new text over it again. If it's a solid colour, you can probably just use al_clear_to_color in conjunction with setting the clip-rectangle to the one that contains the text you need to erase. - Does this link help? https://www.allegro.cc/manual/5/al_clear_to_color

Comment: there is no bitmap so i don't know what to do with this to be honest.

Comment: Apparently, the double-buffer that is displayed when you call al_flip_display is the bitmap that I speak of. I'm on a phone and can't usefully look it up right now, but hopefully this will give you a lead. Failing that, I'd have said what Matthew says below. That's how video games and openGL stuff works - everything is redrawn for each and every frame.

Answer (score 1):

Move the background clear and first three text outputs into the main loop. You need to redraw everything on each frame.

Answer (score 0):

```
//FILE: Main.cpp
//PROGR: Hank Bates
//PURPOSE: To display text on screen for 10 seconds. 
//EXTRA ADD ON FILES: Slendermanswriting.ttf
//                    PrometheusSiren.wav


#include <allegro5\allegro.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_font.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_ttf.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_native_dialog.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_audio.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_acodec.h>




int main(void)
{
    //summon the fonts and stuff
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_FONT *font50;
    ALLEGRO_FONT *font36;
    ALLEGRO_FONT *font18;
    ALLEGRO_SAMPLE *song;
    int a = 100;
    int time_left = 10;

    //test redaw
    ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE *event_queue = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_TIMER *timer = NULL;
    bool redraw = true;

    if (!al_init())
    {
        al_show_native_message_box(NULL, NULL, NULL,
            "failed to initialize allegro!", NULL, NULL);
        return -1;
    }

    //set up some of the display settings
    al_set_new_display_flags(ALLEGRO_WINDOWED | ALLEGRO_RESIZABLE);
    display = al_create_display(640, 480);
    al_set_window_title(display, "A bad horror game");

    if (!display)
    {
        al_show_native_message_box(NULL, NULL, NULL,
            "failed to initialize display!", NULL, NULL);
        return -1;
    }

    al_init_font_addon();
    al_init_ttf_addon();

    //Install Slender Man font here
    font50 = al_load_font("Slendermanswriting.ttf", 50, 0);
    font36 = al_load_font("Slendermanswriting.ttf", 36, 0);
    font18 = al_load_font("Slendermanswriting.ttf", 18, 0);

    //set up music here
    al_install_audio();
    al_init_acodec_addon();
    al_reserve_samples(1);

    //upload the song here
    song = al_load_sample("PrometheusSiren.wav");

    //play song this will loop around and around like a record man!
    al_play_sample(song, 1, 0, 1, ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE_LOOP, NULL);

    int screen_w = al_get_display_width(display);
    int screen_h = al_get_display_height(display);

    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0));

    while (time_left != 0)
    {
        al_flip_display();
        al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0));

        al_draw_text(font50, al_map_rgb(255, 0, 0), 12, 50, 0, "SLENDER MAN IS COMING");
        al_draw_text(font36, al_map_rgb(255, 5, 10), 200, 100, 0,  "RUN AND HIDE");
        al_draw_text(font18, al_map_rgb(100, 15, 18), 150, 150, 0,  "ENJOY THE PROMETHEUS SIREN MUSIC");

        al_draw_textf(font18, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), screen_w / 3, 300, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTRE,
        "TURN UP YOUR VOLUME TO %i PRECENT!", a);

        al_draw_textf(font18, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), screen_w / 2, 400, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTRE,
            "WINDOW WILL CLOSE IN %i seconds!", time_left);

        al_rest(1.0);
        time_left = time_left - 1;
    }

    al_flip_display();
    al_rest(0.0);

    //destroy stuff
    al_destroy_font(font18);
    al_destroy_font(font50);
    al_destroy_font(font36);
    al_destroy_display(display);
    al_destroy_sample(song); 
    al_destroy_timer(timer);
    //pew pew pew, bang.... all destoryed :)

    return 0;
}
```

Yo i got it. Thanks for the point in the right question.